# How can I design a Functor trait to handle trait?

Tags: functional-programming, rust, applicative-functors

In programming languages like Rust, variables of different types that implement the same trait can have different sizes, i.e., the number of bytes used in the memory representation of the type. For example, both `Map<I, F>` and `Filter<I, P>` implement the `Iterator` trait but differ in size. This make it hard to implement `Functor` for the types implementing `Iterator`.

Assuming the Rust language already supports "higher-ranked types," I would like to design a `Functor` trait. However, attempting to implement this trait for the `Iterator` trait directly as shown below would not work:

```rust
trait Functor<F<_>> {
    fn map<A, B>(this: F<A>, f: impl Fn(A) -> B) -> F<B>;
}
```

The reason is that `Iterator` is a trait and not a type constructor, where `Functor` take a type constructor as input. Consequently, we cannot write something like `Functor<Iterator>`.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the Programming Language Design and Implementation StackExchange! Currently, it seems there isn't an answerable question being asked here, as it reads as just statements. Editing your question to ask a specific question would greatly help people know how to answer your question.

Comment: Is this about *applicative* functors, like in the tags, or just functors like the body?  Is it about needing higher-kinded types (to express the same-container, different-contents relationship), or about varying memory allocations? Is it particularly focused on the full Rust language model, or on designing support for functional types in languages more generally? You can [edit] your question to be explicit about what you're looking for.

Comment: What does "size" mean in this context?

Comment: "Size" here means the number of bytes used in the type's memory representation.

Comment: @DavidYoung pretty sure given that OP is referencing Rust it's how much memory the compiler has to allocate to hold the thing in question. I'm not sure what relevance that has to the question either. Although I don't really get the question, I'm not sure where OP got the idea that fmap can return arbitrary types.

Comment: Seems like the trait wants an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#specifying-placeholder-types-in-trait-definitions-with-associated-types) (e.g. `trait F { type Output; ... }`), which is declared by the implementor.

Comment: This question is a strange mix of type theory and representation. While I could answer the representational part, I don't get the question on the type theory side, because I'd expect the type of the functor to be part of the trait's specification instead of the _. Maybe it's just a syntactical issue.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand a bit more now. In Haskell terms, you want to do something akin to `instance Functor Foldable where ...` (not that the particular example I gave there makes complete sense to write in Haskell). This seems like it would cause issues with type class resolution (and, I assume, trait resolution too but I don't really know Rust). Say you have two `Functor` implementations, one for trait `P` and one for trait `Q`. What if you have a type that implements both `P` and `Q`? Which `Functor` implementation gets used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust already has a way to represent `Functor` using [Generic Associated Types (GATs)](https://rust-lang.github.io/generic-associated-types-initiative/explainer/motivation.html):

```rust
pub trait Functor<A> {
    type With<B>: Functor<B>;
    fn map<B>(self, f: impl Fn(A) -> B) -> Self::With<B>;
}
```

In this trait, `Self` is the functor type specialized to `A`, and `With<B>` is the functor type specialized to `B` (`With<B>` is how we emulate "higher-kinded types"). For example:

```rust
/// Dummy functor-able type
pub struct Foonctor<A>(Vec<A>, A);

impl<A> Functor<A> for Foonctor<A> {
    type With<B> = Foonctor<B>;
    fn map<B>(self, f: impl Fn(A) -> B) -> Self::With<B> {
        Foonctor(self.0.into_iter().map(&f).collect(), f(self.1))
    }
}
```

[(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c58a41625a364d242d3546bd0f40c8c2)

Interestingly enough, **using only 2 tiny modifications, we can already make any `Iterator` implement `Functor`** via blanket `impl`. The first modification is to **add the map function's type to `With`, making it `With<F, B>`**; the second modification is to **make `With<B>` *not* the same type as `Self` but with a different parameter, but instead make it [`std::iter::Map<Self, F>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Map.html)**:

```rust
/// New functor trait
pub trait Functor<A> {
    type With<F: Fn(A) -> B, B> = Functor<B>;
    fn map<F: Fn(A) -> B, B>(self, f: F) -> Self::With<F, B>;
}

/// We can still implement the new trait wherever we could implement the old one
impl<A> Functor<A> for Foonctor<A> {
    type With<F: Fn(A) -> B, B> = Foonctor<B>;
    fn map<F: Fn(A) -> B, B>(self, f: F) -> Self::With<F, B> {
        // Same exact implementation as before
        Foonctor(Iterator::map(self.0.into_iter(), &f).collect(), f(self.1))
    }
}

/// But now we can also implement it for arbitrary iterators, using std::iter::Map
impl<A, I: Iterator<Item=A>> Functor<A> for I {
    type With<F: Fn(A) -> B, B> = std::iter::Map<I, F>;
    fn map<F: Fn(A) -> B, B>(self, f: F) -> Self::With<F, B> {
        Iterator::map(self, f)
    }
}
```

[(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b0cef5dfde3a44ab0c916ca443c7e7a0)

However, there's one problem with the above: **the functor `impl` for the iterator trait is a [blanket `impl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861891/what-are-blanket-implementations-in-rust), which [prevents `impl`s for other traits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782573/why-do-blanket-implementations-for-two-different-traits-conflict)**. There's a good reason for this: if `Functor` was blanket implemented for 2 traits, what implementation would an object which implements both traits choose? So until the [specialization RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) gets accepted, this solution is non-ideal.

What we can do, though, is **instead of implementing on the trait directly, use the [newtype pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/newtype.html) and implement it on the newtype**. Then you can use newtypes for other traits as well (this sidesteps the ambiguity problem because even if an object implements multiple traits, you can only choose one newtype to wrap it with and must choose one explicitly)*:

```rust
/// Trait newtype
pub struct IteratorFunctor<A, I: Iterator<Item=A>>(I);

/// Another trait newtype
pub struct FutureFunctor<A, Fut: futures::Future<Output=A>>(Fut);

/// Emulate implementing functor for a trait, by implementing on its newtype
impl<A, I: Iterator<Item=A>> Functor<A> for IteratorFunctor<A, I> {
    /// Note that we also have to wrap the `With` type with the newtype
    type With<F: Fn(A) -> B, B> = IteratorFunctor<B, std::iter::Map<I, F>>;
    fn map<F: Fn(A) -> B, B>(self, f: F) -> Self::With<F, B> {
        IteratorFunctor(self.0.map(f))
    }
}

/// Emulate implementing functor for another trait
impl<A, Fut: futures::Future<Output=A>> Functor<A> for FutureFunctor<A, Fut> {
    type With<F: Fn(A) -> B, B> = FutureFunctor<B, futures::future::Map<Fut, F>>;
    fn map<F: Fn(A) -> B, B>(self, f: F) -> Self::With<F, B> {
        use futures::future::FutureExt;
        FutureFunctor(self.0.map(f))
    }
}

/// Demo
fn main() {
    // Iterator example: [1, 2, ... 10]
    let elems = 1..=10;
    // map (* 2) elems
    let mapped_elems = IteratorFunctor(elems).map(|e| e * 2).0;
    // [2, 4, ... 20]
    println!("{:?}", mapped_elems.collect::<Vec<_>>());
    
    // Future example: { <complex calculation> = "complex calculated value" }
    let future = async {
        // Pretend we're douing some complex calculation with `.await`s here
        "complex calculated value"
    };
    // map length future
    let mapped_future = FutureFunctor(future).map(|f| f.len()).0;
    // { <complex calculation |> length> = 24 }
    println!("{:?}", futures::executor::block_on(mapped_future));
}
```

[Here's the complete finished code (playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=edace1c64f594f26a10d909f14382667)

---

* (In our specific example, this also makes it easier to demo actually using the trait, because `Iterator::map` is already defined. If we demo'd the second-last example, we'd have to explicitly call `Functor::map`, like how we explicitly called `Iterator::map` in the `Foonctor` impl. This isn't an issue for every blanket `impl` in general, it just so happens to be here, because `Functor` isn't the only in-scope trait which defines a method named `map`)

Also, for why this works even though Rust trait implementations can be different sizes: the size of `std::iter::Map<I, F>` is the size of whatever `I` it's given plus the size of `F`. If we call `Functor::map` twice we'll get `IteratorFunctor<C, Map<Map<I, F0>, F1>>`, 3 times and we'll get `IteratorFunctor<D, Map<Map<Map<I, F0>, F1>, F2>>`, etc.; all these types have different sizes, but they're all represented at compile-time and their sizes are known at compile-time.

**If you're doing something where the compiler doesn't know how many times `map` will be called at compile time (e.g. call `map` in a loop): you can convert any iterator into a `Box<dyn Iterator<Item=A>>`, slightly modify `Functor` again (add a lifetime to `With` which bounds `F`), and add another newtype wrapper which returns the same type given the same type parameter:**

```rust
pub trait Functor<A> {
    /// New modification: we have to add a lifetime parameter and bound `F` by it
    type With<'b, F: Fn(A) -> B + 'b, B>: Functor<B> where Self: 'b;
    fn map<'b, F: Fn(A) -> B + 'b, B>(self, f: F) -> Self::With<'b, F, B> where Self: 'b;
}

/// This wrapper doesn't contain the iterator, so we can erase the `std::iter::Map` wrappers.
/// The underlying iterator is allocated on the heap so we don't need to know its size
/// (i.e. how many times `map` was called) at compile-time
pub struct BoxIteratorFunctor<'a, A>(Box<dyn Iterator<Item=A> + 'a>);

impl<'a, A> Functor<A> for BoxIteratorFunctor<'a, A> {
    /// No `std::iter::Map` or `F` in the result type
    type With<'b, F: Fn(A) -> B + 'b, B> = BoxIteratorFunctor<'b, B> where Self: 'b;
    fn map<'b, F: Fn(A) -> B + 'b, B>(self, f: F) -> Self::With<'b, F, B> where Self: 'b {
        BoxIteratorFunctor(Box::new(self.0.map(f)))
    }
}

/// Demo
fn main() {
    // Iterator example: [1, 2, ... 10]
    let mut elems = BoxIteratorFunctor(Box::new(1u64..=10));
    for _ in 1..5 {
        // map (^ 2) elems
        // We can assign to the same variable, because it's the same type:
        //     `BoxIteratorFunctor<'static, u64>`
        elems = elems.map(move |e| e * e);
    }
    // [((((1^2)^2)^2)^2)^2, ((((2^2)^2)^2)^2)^2 ... ((((10^2)^2)^2)^2)^2]
    println!("{:?}", elems.0.collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c98f5063871d2e0659d3fba387b2a805)

Comment: Excellent job! However, I must point out that with this approach, we can't implement the Functor trait for `Iterator`, `Future`, and `Option` all at once...

Comment: Not unless we wrap the `Iterator` and `Future` in newtypes to call `Functor` operations on them, but if we do then it's possible: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b4c68361aa3554094209992ef5edfb30

Comment: There is still one major drawback of this approach: there is no way to constraint the `With<F, B>` has the same type or implement the trait as the implementer. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=570aea7af28f877e739e4c2f5b20ce8d